# How to filter a collection for nested objects with different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, polymorphism, mongodb-.net-driver

In the `Vehicle` collection I have two different types of documents - `Suv` and `Truck`. My models look like this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseCar 
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid Title { get; set; }
   public int YearOfProduction { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Suv : BaseVehicle 
{
   ...
   public List<Engine> Engines { get; set; }
}

public class Truck : BaseVehicle 
{
   ...
   public List<TruckPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class TruckPart 
{
   ...
   public List<Engine> Engines { get; set; }
}

public class Engine 
{
   ...
   public int HorsePower { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to filter the collection of `Vehicles` by their `YearOfProduction` and `HorsePower` and get all `id's` of such vehicles. Is it possible to do it in other way than getting documents of each type separately and then sorting each document of a given type?

```cs
var suv = database.GetCollection<Suv>("vehicles");
var trucks = database.GetCollection<Trucks>("vehicles");

//filters for suvs, trucks and then displaying a list of ids of all matching vehicles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pre-requisites**

To implement the polymorphic concept in MongoDB classes, you need to apply the `BsonKnownTypes` attribute to let the serializer know which inherit/sub-class should be mapped to.

References: [Polymorphism in MongoDB .NET Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/)

```cs
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Suv), typeof(Truck))]
public abstract class BaseVehicle
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int YearOfProduction { get; set; }
}
```

Your BSON Document is required to contain `_t` field which is a discriminator specifying its type. Example:

```
{
  "_id": "4bb69277-f61d-46f2-91ed-1e9b65ddf66d",
  "YearOfProduction": 2020,
  "Engines": [
    {
      "HorsePower": 800
    }
  ],
  "Title": "Suv 2",
  "_t": "Suv"
}
```

---

**Approach 1: With MongoDB .NET Driver Fluent to `BsonDocument`**

With the MongoDB .NET Driver, it is hard to implement the query filter with fluent API (due to strong type), hence the below extension method is to convert the `FilterDefinition<T>` to `BsonDocument`.

```cs
public static class IMongoCollectionExtensions
{
    public static BsonDocument QueryToBson<T>(this IMongoCollection<T> collection,
        FilterDefinition<T> filter)
    {
        return filter.Render(
            collection.DocumentSerializer,
            collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry);
    }
}
```

A bunch of Fluent queries, required to combine them into one as `BsonDocument`.

```cs
IMongoCollection<BaseVehicle> _collection = _db.GetCollection<BaseVehicle>("vehicle");
IMongoCollection<Suv> _suvCollection = _db.GetCollection<Suv>("vehicle");
IMongoCollection<Truck> _truckCollection = _db.GetCollection<Truck>("vehicle");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> _bsonCollection = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("vehicle");

FilterDefinition<Suv> suvFilter = Builders<Suv>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Engines,
    Builders<Engine>.Filter.Eq(y => y.HorsePower, 1000));

FilterDefinition<Truck> truckFilter = Builders<Truck>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Parts,
    Builders<TruckPart>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.Engines,
        Builders<Engine>.Filter.Eq(z => z.HorsePower, 1000)));

FilterDefinition<BaseVehicle> baseFilter = Builders<BaseVehicle>.Filter.Eq(x => x.YearOfProduction, 2022);

FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = _collection.QueryToBson(baseFilter);
filter &= (FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>)_suvCollection.QueryToBson(suvFilter)
    | (FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>)_truckCollection.QueryToBson(truckFilter);

var result = await _collection.Find(_bsonCollection.QueryToBson(filter))
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

**Approach 2: Pass the query as `BsonDocument`**

This approach will be much simple without the Fluent API. As always, you can build your query and convert it into `BsonDocument` with MongoDB Compass (Export to Specific Language).

```
db.collection.find({
  "YearOfProduction": 2022,
  $or: [
    {
      "Engines": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "HorsePower": 1000
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Parts": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Engines": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "HorsePower": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Your query should be as below:

```cs
FilterDefinition<BaseVehicle> filter = new BsonDocument
{
    { "YearOfProduction", 2022 },
    { "$or", new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument("Engines",
                new BsonDocument("$elemMatch",
                    new BsonDocument("HorsePower", 1000))),
            new BsonDocument("Parts",
                new BsonDocument("$elemMatch",
                    new BsonDocument("Engines",
                        new BsonDocument("$elemMatch",
                            new BsonDocument("HorsePower", 1000)))))
        } 
    }
};
```