# Polymorphism In A Single Property

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I implement something like this in MongoDB And EF Core in a .Net 8 Project so that the Type Property can accept TypeA and TypeB Objects and their properties could get stored In The Mongo Document.

```
public class MyObject : Entity
{
 public ParentType Type {get; set;}
}
public class ParentType
{
     // properties
}
public class TypeA: ParentType
{
     // properties
}
public class TypeB: ParentType
{
     // properties
}
```

Comment: you should simplify your question and leave only minimum required information.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to filter a collection for nested objects with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75259584). You need to apply the `BsonKnownTypes` attribute in your base class.

Comment: That question is about MongoDB Driver, I'm asking about EF Core. certainly I put `BsonKnownTypes` and all the things I found in other questions, guess what?? it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AmirhoseinRahmati afaik ef core does not currently support  mongodb  or has that changed?

Comment: @sommmen So, let me give you the good news, that has indeed changed.(that's my current problem, there's no good documentation for it, no question in stackoverflow in this topic, NOTHING, I'm stuck in the middle of the air, hahaha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the MongoDB EF Core Driver that I'm using is in the preview version for .Net 7, the feature I'm trying to use mentioned as "Type Discriminators" in the Nuget Packages' Repository in github, is not currently available in this version, so currently, my question has no correct answer.